# How to convert foreach to Parallel.Foreach in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, foreach, .net-framework-version

I have a `foreach` loop like shown below

```
ArrayList list;
list = ftp.GetFileList(remotepath<ftp://ftp.getfilelist(remotepath/>);

foreach (string item in list)
{
}
```

I converted to a `Parallel.Foreach` like shown below without luck

```
ArrayList list;
list = ftp.GetFileList(remotepath<ftp://ftp.getfilelist(remotepath/>);

Parallel.ForEach(list.ToArra(), item => 
{
    if (item.StartsWith("GExport_") &&(!item.ToUpper().Contains("DUM")))
    {
    }
}
```

It throws error like item does not contain `StartsWith()` extension method. How to solve it?

Comment: Please take the time to format your post correctly next time.

Comment: You can't just make a function parallel, even if you fix your syntax errors. You now have multiple threads reading and writing to your variables at the same time, you need to make sure the classes that those variables represent can handle it.

Comment: `(remotepath<ftp://ftp.getfilelist(remotepath/>);` could not ever compile in C#.

Comment: after using the answer of DaveShaw i am getting now error at ftp.get something like "value was invalid". how to correct it

Comment: @peter the problem you are having is the problem I was trying to warn you about. You can't just have multiple threads use `ftp` at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the `foreach` is converting the items in the `ArrayList` to `string` from an `object`. All the items in an `ArrayList` are `object` at compile time, and `object` doesn't have a method called `StartsWith`.

In this case:

```
foreach (string item in list)
```

`item` is converted into a `string` from `object`.

To do the same you will need to perform the conversion yourself e.g.

```
Parallel.ForEach(list.OfType<string>().ToArray(), item ....
```

Or `.Cast<string>` instead of `OfType` if you want to fail at runtime if there's a non-string instance in your `list`.

Alternatively use a generic list such as `List<String>` to avoid runtime casting.

Comment: Minor thing - to be more equivalent, it should be `.Cast<string>` rather than `OfType<string>` - assuming we want to fail hard and fast (as the original code does) when we find a non-string in `list`

Comment: He also needs to look in to the thread safety of his objects. He is now going to be using `ftp`, the local to the function (but not to the parallel lambada) variable `path`, and `download_location_hw` from multiple threads

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain i am getting now error at ftp.get something like "value was invalid". how to correct it